# VHDL "Process": Incorrect usage of process?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm brand new to VHDL and the Quartus design environment, and I'm trying to run the simulation of some textio but I must be missing something... When I compile the following code (which I borrowed snippets of from an OSU VHDL textio guide (http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/vhdl_lectures/text_io.pdf), I get error 10533:

> Error (10533): VHDL Wait Statement error at tio_top.vhd(36): Wait Statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword

What type of condition is appropriate to use in this scenario? I've tried creating a condition that evaluates to a constant true or false, but that gives an error also.
Perhaps my understanding of *process* is wrong and it needs to continuously run?
Basically I just want to output variable a to a text file... Do I need to create a testbench?

```
library ieee;
library std;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
use ieee.math_complex.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity tio_top is
end tio_top;

architecture main of tio_top is
begin
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  --practice with textio
  file_io: --declare a process for executing file input/output
  process is
    file out_file : text open read_mode is "out_values"; --declare output file name
    variable out_line : line; --declare variable of type line to store values
    variable a : std_logic; --declare other logic varialbes for playing around with     
  begin --put the meet of the textio here

    a := '1';

    write(out_line,a);
    writeline(out_file, out_line);

    wait; --allows simulation to halt!

  end process;

end main;
```

Comment: See [wait statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782358/wait-statement-must-contain-condition-clause-with-until-keyword). Are you trying to synthesis your VHDL design? You also can't write to a read_mode file.

Comment: Changing the out_values file declaration to write_mode, using a simulator and your code produces a file out_values containing the value `1`, despite all the superfluous use clauses. You're experiencing tool issues.

Comment: Quartus is a logic synthesizer. It does not accept the complete VHDL language but only a subset that makes sense for logic synthesis. Text file I/Os, pointers (the `line` type is an access type, the VHDL pointers) or the eternal `wait` statement are not part of this subset (what hardware would you expect?).

Comment: Wait statement in this process is right.But it is only for similation not for synthesize.

Comment: If you want to simulate, use mentor graphics modelsim, "included" with the Intel/Alters tools. The Quatus ISE is for synthesis, not for simulation.

Comment: @user1155120 Thank you! Instead of using NativeLink to import a simulator, I just took the file straight to ModelSim software and simulated there.