# Is there any error in the VHDL code and testbench?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I have been trying a clocked flip flop in Quartus 2 and I received the following error

> Error (10533): VHDL Wait Statement error at T17_ClockedProcessTb.vhd(42): Wait Statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword

I have created the following code for the Flip Flop

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity T17_FlipFlop is
port (
      clk: in std_logic;
      nRst: in std_logic;
        Input: in std_logic;
        Output: out std_logic);
        end entity;
        
architecture rtl of T17_FlipFlop is
begin 
     process(Clk) is
      begin 
           if rising_edge(Clk) then
                 if nRst= '0' then
                     Output<= '0';
                  else
                     Output<= Input;
                  end if;
             end if;
     end process;
end architecture;
```

Also I have created a testbench for this

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity T17_ClockedProcessTb is
end entity;

architecture sim of T17_ClockedProcessTb is
    constant ClockFrequency : integer := 100e6; --100 MHz
     constant ClockPeriod : time := 1000 ms; 
     
     signal ClK : std_logic := '1';
     signal nRst: std_logic := '0';
     signal Input: std_logic:= '0';
     signal Output: std_logic;

    begin
        --The Device Under Test (DUT)
         i_FlipFlop : entity work.T17_FlipFlop(rtl)
         port map(
                  ClK => Clk,
                     nRst => nRst,
                     Input => Input,
                     Output => Output);
         --Process for generating clock 
         Clk <= not Clk after ClockPeriod /2 ;
         --Testbench sequence
         process is
         begin 
             --The the DUT out of reset 
              nRst<= '1';
              
              --wait for 20 ns;
              Input<= '1' after 20 ns;
              --wait for 22 ns;
              Input<= '0' after 22 ns;
              --wait for 6  ns;
              Input<= '1' after 6 ns;
              --wait for 20 ns;
              
              --Reset the DUT
              nRst<= '0' after 20 ns;
              wait;
              
         end process;
end architecture;
```

I compiled the first code and then the second on but I got an error in doing the same?

What can I do to remove them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wait statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782358/wait-statement-must-contain-condition-clause-with-until-keyword)

Comment: There isn't a VHDL error, there's an issue with specifying the testbench as the top of your design in Quartus. See [wait statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782358/wait-statement-must-contain-condition-clause-with-until-keyword). Your clock period should be 10 ns not 1000 ms. The reset is the wrong polarity or not released. There's likely another error in there somewhere.

Comment: I got the required results. It is the issue with the placing of the file.